# General term for “electronics”, “thermotechnics”, etc

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I need a term that generalizes following areas:

electronics
mechanic engineering
mechatronics
thermotechnics
etc.,
but not includes: 
gene engineering
drug engineering
etc.

Thus, “engineering” does not fit in my case.
I was suggested “technology”. But it was not by native speakers. Thus I would like native speakers to chek or suggest more appropriate word.
Can it be “technical engineering”, “technics”?

Comment: Can you explain what distinguishes the areas you want to include from the areas you don't want to include? Why are the included ones included? Why are the excluded ones excluded?

Comment: It looks like the underlying distinction is between *physics* and *biology* *(**biotech**)*.

Comment: Are these being segregated as topics, as academic disciplines, or as something else? That is, is the intent to separate the technological/scientific disciplines as electrical/mechanical/technological engineering versus biological/chemical/physical engineering?

Comment: @DJClayworth These are the areas to which the term "engineering" was originally applied (and to other areas that are not included, such as "biological engineering") was extended later. These are the areas where we deal with completely man-made things, not natural things.
It is difficult to explain :). In Russian, there is a special word for this. And I don't know if there's a direct analogue in English.
Perhaps psosuna's writing is close to my intention.

Answer (score 3):

Some ideas that may work or may inspire better answers:

- Non-biochemical engineering
- Inorganic engineering

The idea here is, very generally speaking, differentiating non-carbon-based vs. carbon-based.

Comment: Thank you. I seem “Inorganic engineering” fits. But I cannot judge because I am not a native speaker

Comment: As a native speaker "Inorganic engineering" would be unusual. People would probably ask you what it meant at first, but once it's explained it would probably be easily remembered.

Comment: @DJClayworth Thank you. And what you can say about "technology"?

Comment: I would not exclude biological engineering from "technology". But this is an area where people's associations are going to be different.